# react-laravel redirect issue from middleware

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I don’t used react-router, just simply used react with blade. Like 
following:
**articleManage.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    <div id="articleManage"></div>
@stop
```

I try to use jwt authentication, and it works.
Here is my jwt auth middleware:
**authJWT.php**

```
try {
    $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();
    if (! $token->authenticate()) {
        return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Invalid 1']);
    }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Expired 2']);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Something is wrong 3']);
    }
}
return $next($request);
```

Now I am stuck with redirection on middleware, cause it won’t work when I change it like this:

```
try {
    $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();
    if (! $token->authenticate()) {
        return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ……
    return redirect('/');
}
return $next($request);
```

**And this is the error message I got:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ArticleManage.render (app.js:54105)
    at app.js:50033
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (app.js:49313)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (app.js:50032)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (app.js:50059)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (app.js:49983)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (app.js:49961)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (app.js:49882)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (app.js:49798)
    at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (app.js:2916)
```

**Any idea how to redirect when token error?**

10/17: this is my program flow 
**articleManage.js**

```
let url = 'load-article';
let config = {
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')}
};

axios.get(url,config).then(response=>{
    this.setState({'articles':response.data.articles});
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/load-article', 'API\ArticleController@read')->middleware('jwt-auth');
```

**ArticleController@read**

```
public function read(Request $request){
    $header = $request->header('Authorization');
    $articles = Article::All();
    return response()->json(['articles' => $articles]);
}
```

now I change middleware, cause I want to try redirection, then I get error.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
//        try {
//            $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();
//            if (! $token->authenticate()) {
//                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
//            }
//        } catch (Exception $e) {
//            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
//                return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Invalid 1']);
//            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
//                return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Expired 2']);
//            }else{
//                return response()->json(['error'=>'Something is wrong 3']);
//            }
//        }
//        return $next($request);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: can you be specific in your tags. You use `php`, `js`, `laravel` etc.

Comment: show us an error that you get

Comment: @jimmy good, it is a javascript error, and to be able to solve it I need your js file where the error comes from

Comment: @lankovova I add program flow and code, thanks for help :)

Comment: hello, anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark here, since you didn't post the whole articleManager component. But, make sure you're passing some sort of failure status code header on all error responses. Otherwise, Axios will read `response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Invalid 1'])` as a success and attempt to set state. Since `response.data.articles` is undefined, that's why you're getting the error. So change your middleware in authJWT.php to something like:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Invalid 1'], 500);
    } else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Expired 2'], 500);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Something is wrong 3'], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Finially I know that what is going wrang.